# Flutter/Dart: How to make tabs only render once?

Tags: tabs, dart, flutter, render

I currently have three tabs navigated with bottom nav bar, however I have just noticed that it actually re-renders every tab change. How can I fix this so it only renders once, and uses that render until manual refresh (which will be implemented later on).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../styles.dart';

import 'one.dart';
import 'two.dart';
import 'three.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final List<Widget> _children = [ One(), Two(), Three(), ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text( 'RefLog', style: Styles.headerLarge ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: TabBarView(
            children: _children,
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab( text: 'One', icon: Icon(Icons.import_contacts, size: 20.0) ),
              Tab( text: 'Two', icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant, size: 20.0) ),
              Tab( text: 'Three', icon: Icon(Icons.record_voice_over, size: 20.0) ),
            ],
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white30,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check this post: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc

Comment: Perfect (again)! Thanks :)

Comment: IndexedStack worked better for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598900/flutter-bottomnavigationbar-rebuilds-page-on-change-of-tab