# Flutter googlemaps reloads everytime I change page in tabnavigator

Tags: flutter

[image: Map loads everytime I go back to MapPage]

Hello, I'm trying to use Flutter and the new googlemaps plugin in my application. My problem is that everytime I change page in the tabnav I it will reload googlemaps widget. I tried using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin but that didn't help. I will keep trying to figure this out, but help is appreciated or if somebody knows what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:restapoints/pages/pages.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Flutter App',
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    MapPage(),
    QrPage(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: _children[_currentIndex], // new
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped, // new
        currentIndex: _currentIndex, // new
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
            title: Text('Messages'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

MapPage:

```
    class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
    }

    class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage>
        with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MapPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      ///Getting size of the screen from [MediaQuery] inherited widget.
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            options: GoogleMapOptions(
              compassEnabled: true,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              trackCameraPosition: true,
            ),
          ),

          ///If not enabled don't show ListView of places.
          toggleListView
              ? Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                  left: 10,
                  child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        children: _places.map((place) {
                          return _placeCard(place);
                        }).toList(),
                      )),
                )
              : Container()
        ],
      ),
    );

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: this is something similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598900/flutter-bottomnavigationbar-rebuilds-page-on-change-of-tab

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598900/flutter-bottomnavigationbar-rebuilds-page-on-change-of-tab Solved my problem!

"You need to wrap every root page (the first page you see when you press a bottom navigation item) with a navigator and put them in a Stack."

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the page a StatefulWidget like MapPage, I added the Widget inside an [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) to prevent rebuild of the page. Though the downside of this approach is that the page might take time to build if there's a lot of pages added on Stack.