# Problem with persistent bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have persistent bottom navigation bar across my whole app but exclude bottom navigation bar in some routes like login page.

I created BottomNavigationBar widget:

```
  class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {

       final int bottomIndex;
       const MyBottomNavigationBar({Key key, this.bottomIndex}) : 
       super(key: key);

        State createState() => _MyBottomNavigationBarState();
          }

        class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State 
               <MyBottomNavigationBar> {
             @override
           Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(LineIcons.film),
        title: Text(
          '1',
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(LineIcons.ticket),
        title: Text(
          '2',
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(LineIcons.user),
        title: Text(
          '3',
        ),
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: widget.bottomIndex,
    onTap: (int index) {
      setState(() {
        switch (index) {
          case 0 :
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            break;
          case 1:
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyTickets()));
            break;
          case 2:
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainProfile()));
            break;
        }
      });
    }
    );
```

}
}

Then in build() of each page where i want to create BottomNavigationBar I write:
             bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(bottomIndex: 0,)
                           or
            bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(bottomIndex: 1,),
                             or
            bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(bottomIndex: 2,),

Everything is ok, but I have a problem: each time when I open ANY page with bottomNavigationBar, my main page (HomePage()) is rebuild and call methods from api. How can I avoid it? Thank you

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. Please check the question guidelines:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement this using the indexed stack. Just check this link in which you might get the desired output.

[Flutter: BottomNavigationBar rebuilds Page on change of tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598900/flutter-bottomnavigationbar-rebuilds-page-on-change-of-tab)