# How do I execute FutureBuilder only once in a list that gets reinitialized?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a Flutter project that has a home page with a bottom navigation bar. I used an IndexedStack as the body.

I'm trying to make my CustomList() a feed which shows the most recent documents.
I intend to use pagination too.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final widgetOptions = [
    CustomList(),
    Page2(),
    Page3(),
    Page4(),
  ];

  int _selectedItemPosition = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(    
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
       //
        currentIndex: _selectedItemPosition,
        onPositionChanged: (index) => setState(() {
          _selectedItemPosition = index;
        }),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(),
          BottomNavigationBarItem()
        ],
      ),

      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedItemPosition,
        children: widgetOptions,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code of my CustomList():

```
class CustomList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _CustomListState createState() => _CustomListState();
}

class _CustomListState extends State<CustomList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Future<Object> getData()
    {
     //get Data from server
    }


    return FutureBuilder<Object>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if(snapshot.data != null)
        {
          if(snapshot.hasData)
          {
           //get Documents
          }


            return ListView.builder(
              //
              itemBuilder: (context , index) {
                //return a widget that uses the data received from the snapshot
              },
            );
          }

        }

    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that every time I change the page using the bottom navigation bar, whenever I come back to my default page with the CustomList(), the FutureBuilder is fired again resulting in my list having duplicates. This is due to the CustomList() being initialized again.

How do I structure my code so that the FutureBuilder is executed only once and isn't fired repeatedly when I use the BottomNavigationBar to change the page?

Comment: one way is to use the `FutureBuilder` in `_HomeState` to fetch the data and then just pass it down to `CustomList` widget. This way you will not call the API each time the widget is rebuilt again

Comment: I've tried this, but the FutureBuilder still gets fired.

Comment: In fact, I've put the whole code of CustomList() wrapped by the FutureBuilder in the initState() method of _HomeState. It still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: can you check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598900/flutter-bottomnavigationbar-rebuilds-page-on-change-of-tab) and see if it helps ... the difference I see is that instead of creating the List of widgets it is being passed from the parent

Answer (score 0):

This is because you get a new future every time `build` is called, because you pass a function call to the `FutureBuilder` and not a reference that stays the same.
There are several easy options to solve this.

1. You can store a reference to the future and pass this reference to the `FutureBuilder`
2. You can use an `AsyncMemoizer` from the `async` package to only run the future once https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/AsyncMemoizer-class.html
3. You can use the `FutureProvider` from the `provider` package https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/FutureProvider-class.html