# BottomNavigationBar rebuilds child Page on change of tab even with IndexedStack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

I have used this [Flutter: BottomNavigationBar rebuilds Page on change of tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598900/flutter-bottomnavigationbar-rebuilds-page-on-change-of-tab)

and this article https://medium.com/@theboringdeveloper/common-bottom-navigation-bar-flutter-e3693305d2d

Had fixed it a bit, and now I am able to prevent direct root pages from being rebuilt. If you are still interested in how you can prevent root pages rebuilt, you can look through the gits and ask a question.

Gist it self: https://gist.github.com/Turbozanik/2149b763a414a35a249cfdd5a170f44f

**The question is how can I prevent a child page from rebuilt. Will clarify it a bit.**

```
child1
  |
toot1 root2 root3 root4
```

Here all the root pages will not be rebuilt, but the child page in the tab will be rebuilt, is there any way I can keep the whole tab from rebuilding instead of just the root pages.**(SPOILER: The only way, I was able to keep root pages is by creating a static list of root pages. Gist line 15.)**

**UPDATE: I have tested the widget behaviour when its rebuilt, in my case it even don't change the scroll position, so I am fine even with rebuilted widget(have no idea how it works it somehow is rebuilt into exactly the same state it was before the rebuild) But I am still interested how can I prevent the rebuild.**