# how to manage tabs in flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 tabs in my application and there is a date picker which is same for all the tabs whenever i choose the date (from which ever tab it may be)all the data in 3 tabs will change corresponding to the choosen date and so many apis have been provided to this.
But the problem is every time whenever i switch the tab all the apis are hiting again.so how can i manage the tabs so that it will not hit the apis on switching until i choose the date again

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  SelectedDates _selectedDates = SelectedDates();
  List<DateTime> selectedDates = List();
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _children = [
    FirstPage(),
    ChartPage(),
    ActionPage(),
  ];

  onTabSelected(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _homeProvider = Provider.of<HomeProvider>(context);
    final _chartProvider = Provider.of<ChartListingProvider>(context);
    final _actionProvider = Provider.of<ActionProvider>(context);
    showDatePickerDialog(BuildContext context) async {
      final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialFirstDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2015),
        initialLastDate: (DateTime.now()).add(
          Duration(days: 7),
        ),
        lastDate: DateTime(2025),
      );
      if (picked != null && picked.length == 2 && picked != selectedDates) {
        setState(() {
          selectedDates = picked;
          var formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
          _selectedDates?.fromDate = formatter.format(picked[0]);
          _selectedDates?.endDate = formatter.format(picked[1]);

             _actionProvider.setDate(_selectedDates);

          _chartProvider.setDate(_selectedDates);

          _homeProvider.setDate(_selectedDates);
         
        });
      }
    }

    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Hive.box(userDetailsBox).listenable(),
      builder: (_, Box box, __) {
        String token = box.get(authTokenBoxKey);
        String id = box.get(companyIdBoxKey);
        
         _actionProvider.setTokenAndCompanyId(token, id);
         //in the above function i have provided the apis related to third tab
        _chartProvider.setTokenAndCompanyId(token, id);
        //in the above function i have provided the apis related to second tab
        __homeProvider.setTokenAndCompanyId(token, id);
         //in the above function i have provided the apis related to first tab
        
          return DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            initialIndex: 1,
            child: Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showDatePickerDialog(context);
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.date_range),
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              ),
              
              appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Tab Controller"), actions: <Widget>[]),
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                onTap: onTabSelected,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    title: Text("Home"),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                    title: Text("Chart"),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.redo),
                    title: Text("Action"),
                  ),
                ],
                currentIndex: _currentIndex,
              ),
              body: _children[_currentIndex],
            ),
          );
       
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `setstate` which force your whole widget to rebuild.

```
onTabSelected(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

For this case you can use providers or other State Management librarys out there like [RXdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart), [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod), [Providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or anything else.

These state management librarys give you access to the states and notifies about changes without rebuilding the whole tree. There are a lot of concepts out there you can explore by googling.

### Implementation

This is an example implementation using Providers package:
NavigationNotifier:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  get currentIndex => _currentIndex;

  set currentIndex(int index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Your main file/ home, whatever:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> _children = [Screen1(), Screen2()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<NavigationNotifier>(context);
...
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                onTap: (index) {
                  provider.currentIndex = index;
                },
                currentIndex: provider.currentIndex,
                showSelectedLabels: true,
                showUnselectedLabels: true,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.home), label: 'home'),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle_outlined),
                      label: 'Profile')
                ],
              ),
              body: _children[provider.currentIndex]),
```

Comment: thanks for the response sir Marcel Dz. Got your point and implimented with provider as you mentioned but still the problem remains same with the index change it again rebuilts  from build().please help to fix this issue

Comment: did you remove every setstate?

Comment: yes i removed that but it didnt worked for  and next have tried implement using indexed stack in body: IndexedStack(
                  index: _provider.currentIndex,
                  children: <Widget>[
                 FirstPage(), ChartPage(),  ActionPage(),
                  ]) that also didnt worked

Comment: i followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55512883/12953031 but it didnt worked