# Flutter: persistent bottom navigation bar rebuilds ALL pages when navigating between pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using the [persistent_bottom_nav_bar package](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) and have implemented its custom navigation bar (basically just customized from the example in their Readme page). Reproducible code below.

**The issue**: when you navigate with the bottom navigation, ALL the pages rebuild on every tap. Quite draining on the app's performance! This seems to be a Flutter issue in general and solutions are given by using e.g. [an IndexedStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598900/flutter-bottomnavigationbar-rebuilds-page-on-change-of-tab) when the full code is written by oneself instead of using a package, which I have done.

Is there any way to fix this issue when using the persistent_bottom_nav_bar package and specifically with the custom code that I have used?

My code (simplified so that anyone can just copy & run it):

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';

import 'page1.dart';
import 'page2.dart';
import 'page3.dart';
import 'page4.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: HomeScaffold(),
    );
  }
  }

class HomeScaffold extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScaffoldState createState() => _HomeScaffoldState();
}

class _HomeScaffoldState extends State<HomeScaffold> {
  PersistentTabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      Page1(),
      Page2(),
      Page3(),
      Page4(),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      _buildBottomNavBarItem('Page 1', Icons.home),
      _buildBottomNavBarItem('Page 2', Icons.search),
      _buildBottomNavBarItem('Page 3', Icons.message),
      _buildBottomNavBarItem('Page 4', Icons.settings),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentTabView.custom(
      context,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      itemCount: 4,
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
      stateManagement: true,
      screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
        animateTabTransition: true,
        curve: Curves.ease,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      ),
      customWidget: CustomNavBarWidget(
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        onItemSelected: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _controller.index = index;
          });
        },
        selectedIndex: _controller.index,
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomNavBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  final List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> items;
  final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelected;

  CustomNavBarWidget({
    Key key,
    this.selectedIndex,
    @required this.items,
    this.onItemSelected,
  });

  Widget _buildItem(PersistentBottomNavBarItem item, bool isSelected) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: IconTheme(
              data: IconThemeData(
                  size: 26.0,
                  color: isSelected
                      ? (item.activeColorSecondary == null
                      ? item.activeColorPrimary
                      : item.activeColorSecondary)
                      : item.inactiveColorPrimary == null
                      ? item.activeColorPrimary
                      : item.inactiveColorPrimary),
              child: isSelected ? item.icon : item.inactiveIcon ?? item.icon,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.transparency,
              child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text(
                    item.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: isSelected
                            ? (item.activeColorSecondary == null
                            ? item.activeColorPrimary
                            : item.activeColorSecondary)
                            : item.inactiveColorPrimary,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 12.0),
                  )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: items.map((item) {
            int index = items.indexOf(item);
            return Flexible(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  this.onItemSelected(index);
                },
                child: _buildItem(item, selectedIndex == index),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

PersistentBottomNavBarItem _buildBottomNavBarItem(String title, IconData icon) {
  return PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
    icon: Icon(icon),
    title: title,
    activeColorPrimary: Colors.indigo,
    inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, this won't refresh page while change tab:

1.

```
  class PageState extends State<Page> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
```

2. ```
   @override
   bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
   ```
3. ```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     super.build(context);
   ```

Comment: I'm already using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` on tabs (within the same page) and it works fine there. However, for the persistent bottom navigation (the main pages), this unfortunately doesn't work. Feel free to copy the code I've pasted above and try for yourself. Thanks.